# Open preimage implies open?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f:X \to Y$ be continuous, i.e every open subset of $Y$ has an open preimage under $f$. I wonder if the converse is true:

Let $U$ be some subset of $Y$. If $f^{-1}(U)\subset X$ is open, does it follow that $U$ is open?

Comment: Of course not : if $f$ is constant, for instance then $f^{-1}(U)$ is $X$ or emptyset for any $U$, which is open. If $Y$ has non open sets...

Comment: With $U=f(X)$  we have $f^{-1}(U)=X$ is open in $X .$ But $f(X)$ doesn't have to be open in $Y.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, consider $U = [0,1)$ and $f(x) = x^2$ from the real numbers to itself in the standard topologies.

Answer (score 2):

Not, it's not true. Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=1$. Clearly $f$ is continuous. Then, $f^{-1}[\{1\}]=\mathbb{R}$, i.e., the inverse image of $\{1\}$ is an open set, but, $\{1\}$ is not open (we are using the euclidean topology).